# How to enable TouchPosition[ ... , 2]?

Tags: graphics, front-end

It appears that the mechanics of the Front End prevent `TouchPosition` from working as expected. My plan is to keep track of the position of the second touch using `TouchPosition["Graphics",2]` in the code below. The user would make a first touch on the graph, then write on it with the second touch. However, when I make the second touch and move it, then the zoom factor of the Front End changes, instead of the second touch being tracked. How can I actually track the second touch? By the way, I am using Windows 10 on a Surface laptop.

Code in question:

```
mymouse := Block[{}, pos = TouchPosition["Graphics",2];
  If[pos =!= None, AppendTo[posList, pos];
   posList = DeleteDuplicates@posList;]]
posList = {};
Dynamic[Graphics[Line@posList, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> Medium, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 6}, {0, 4}}]]
Dynamic[mymouse]
```

By contrast, this code works as expected if instead of tracking touch, I track the mouse with `pos=MousePosition["Graphics"];`.

Comment: What system are you using? (I can't help probably, since I don't have a touchscreen, but it might be important.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`TouchPosition` and `GestureHandler` are only supported in Wolfram Player on iOS.